# How does live auto-complete for text inputs work in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, nlp

I'm wondering how live text parsing works in Python in order to take parts of a text input and match them up with a dictionary for auto-completion. In this specific case, they're "plans" like "soccer," "basketball," "knitting," "drawing," etc. matched up with emojis for auto-completion. (similar to Venmo's emoji auto-complete, if that provides more context)

This might elicit responses on how auto-complete generally works, but I'm wondering how this works specifically for Python NLP.

Comment: Could you give more details? Maybe add some code example where you want to make this auto-complete work...

Comment: The dictionary would look something like this: https://github.com/dasmer/EmojiAutocompleteExample/blob/master/Carthage/Build/iOS/EmojiKit.framework/AllEmoji.json. The author, Dasmer Singh, was the chief developer behind Venmo's original emoji auto-complete. I'm wondering how live text auto-complete works in Python from a conceptual standpoint, rather than having any written code just yet.